# Can DD-WRT create two WIFI ssid's one that routes through a VPN and the other that does not?

Tags: router, vpn, dd-wrt, openvpn

I am living in China and need a VPN to access youtube, facebook etc. However it is considerably slower to access local sites through a VPN. I am thinking to buy a router that will allow me to simply switch between 'wifi networks' to have vpn on or off.

Does anyone know if DD-WRT supports such a feature? Can anyone recommend a suitable router? I was looking at the Asus RT-N13 it looks to have good specs for the price.

The router needs to be able to support functioning as an OpenVPN client as PPTP is blocked here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use DD-WRT, you don't need multiple SSIDs to accomplish what you want.  You may just use routing, through static routes, to send the access through VPN or not.

Set you default route to your VPN connection and add a static route to China IP range to pass out of your VPN.